# WCF Service - Performance testing with jMeter

Tags: wcf, rest, jmeter, wcf-rest

I have developed a RESTful `WCF` service (`WebHttpBinding`). I ran a performance test using jMeter. The test plan contained one operation in the service, which will be called in 100 concurrent threads. However, I noticed that after running the test, `the first 20 to 30 threads are taking considerable amount of time to get the response (say 10-15 seconds)` and then all the other remaining threads will complete their execution in 2-3 seconds. It seems to me as if the first few threads are blocking the threads that reach the server after them.

My service has the below configurations:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

And also,

```
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="300" maxConcurrentSessions="300"/>
```

Could someone please give some pointers as to what is causing this initial delay?

Comment: Alter your maxConcurrentInstances as well - but bear in mind the number of concurrent events is controlled by your number of cores... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.servicethrottle.maxconcurrentinstances.aspx tells you a bit more about the concurrent instances.

Comment: If you are using database, then maybe it is taking a long time to open those connections? Or maybe you are using caching and after few requests you've got your results obtained from cache?